# Getting Request User on Django Rest Oauth2

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0

I'm using the [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) with the [Django Oauth Toolkit](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit).

I'm connecting fine. I have no issues with the token, access and permissions.

But I'd like to have a queryset with a filter of the current user something like:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
    return Account.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

When I do this, the user I get is a None Type. Even though I was able to pass correctly the **Token** via **Authorization Bearer**.

The oAuth2 application created for this has the following settings:

- client type: confidential
- authorization grant type: client credentials